# How do I insert the identifier into a hash table in C?

Tags: c, syntax, compiler-construction

I think I may have it. From the code, does it get the identifier properly? Or should I be approaching it differently? I don't know if I should be adding a IDENT case to the main instead of the check_identifier, or keep the check _identifier to tie in the hash table.

```
//main.c
#include "symtab.c

FILE *file;

char buffer[1000 + 1];  // + 1 for the null terminator.
char tokens[1000 + 1];
char ctype[20];

int index = 0;
int line_num = 0;
int line_row = 0;
int line_column = 0;
int max_token = 0;

typedef enum
{
    WORD,       // Consists of a string of letters.
    SEPARATOR,  // Consists of a single separator.
    SPACE,      // Consists of a single space character.
    NELI,
    NUMBER,
    OPERATOR,
    EQUALIZER,
    UNKNOWN,    // Consists of a single unknown character.
    IDENT,
    ENFI,
} token_type;

token_type token;

char predirect[][12] = { "use", "system",  "label",  "translate"};

void library(char t[])
{
    int i;

    for (i = 0; i < 5; i++)
    {
        if (strcmp(t, predirect[i]) == 0)
        {
            strcpy(ctype, predirect[i]);    //If Keyword, set 'ctype' as that token.
            printf(" %03d:   %s\t              Predirect\n", line_num, t);
            return;
        }
    }
    check_identifier(buffer);
}

int check_identifier(char buf[])
{
    line_num++;

    strcpy(tokens, buf);
    printf(" %03d:   %s                     Identifier\n", line_num, tokens);

    insert(tokens, strlen(tokens), UNDEF, line_row);

    return IDENT;
}

get_char(FILE *file, char *const buf, const int max_token)
{

    int length = 0;
    int ch;

    if ((ch = fgetc(file)) == EOF) 
    {
        return ENFI;
    }

    buffer[length++] = ch;
    buffer[length] = 0;                        /* In case 'ch' is separator, space, or unknown. */

    if (seperator(ch))
    {
        return SEPARATOR;
    }

    if (space(ch))
    {
        return SPACE;
    }

    if (neli(ch))
    {
        return NELI;
    }
    if (number(ch))
    {
        return NUMBER;
    }
    if (operators(ch))
    {
        return OPERATOR;
    }

    if (equalizer(ch))
    {
        return EQUALIZER;
    }

    if (!letter(ch))
    {
        return UNKNOWN;
    }

    while ((ch = fgetc(file)) != EOF && length < max_token) 
    {
        // If we see a non-letter, put it back on the input stream.
        if (!letter(ch)) 
        {
            ungetc(ch, file);
            break;
        }
        buffer[length++] = ch;
    }
    buffer[length] = 0;

    return WORD;
}

get_token()
{
    strcpy(ctype, "NULL");  //Initialising as "NULL"

    while ((token = get_char(file, buffer, 1000 + 1)) != ENFI)
    {
        line_num++;

        switch (token)
        {
        case SEPARATOR:
            printf(" %03d:   %s\t              Separator\n", line_num, buffer);
            break;
        case SPACE:
            printf("", buffer);
            break;
        case NELI:
            printf("%s", buffer);
            break;
        case NUMBER:
            printf(" %03d:   %s\t              Number\n", line_num, buffer);
            break;
        case OPERATOR:
            printf(" %03d:   %s\t              Operator\n", line_num, buffer);
            break;
        case EQUALIZER:
            printf(" %03d:   %s\t              Equalizer\n", line_num, buffer);
            break;
        case WORD:
            library(buffer);
            break;
        case UNKNOWN:
            printf(" %03d: \tASCII value %d       \tUnknown\n", line_num, buffer[0]);
            break;
        default:
            break;
        }
    }
}

int main()
{
    init_hash_table();

    file = fopen("source.txt", "r");
    get_token();

    listing = fopen("output.txt", "w");
    symtab_dump(listing);

    fclose(file);
    return 0;
}
```

I have been working with this hash table, and trying to get it to fit.

```
//Symtab.c
#include "type.h"

/* maximum size of hash table */
#define size 211

/* maximum size of tokens-identifiers */
#define token_length 40

/* token types */
#define UNDEF 0
#define NUM_TYPE 1
#define DECI_TYPE 2
#define STRAND_TYPE 3
#define LOGIC_TYPE 4
#define LIST_TYPE 5
#define FUNCTION_TYPE 6

/* how parameter is passed */
#define BY_VALUE 1
#define BY_REFER 2
#define max_children 3

/* current scope */
int cur_scope = 0;

/* parameter struct */
typedef struct Trade 
{
    int trade_type;
    char trade_name[token_length];
    // to store value
    int num_value; double decii_value; char *symbol_strand_value;
    int passing; // value or reference
}Trade;

/* a linked list of references (lineno's) for each variable */
typedef struct reference_list
{
    int line_row;
    struct  reference_list *next;
    int type;
} reference_list;

// struct that represents a list node
typedef struct list_node
{
    char symbol_table_name[token_length];
    int symbol_table_size;
    int scope;
    reference_list *lines;

    // to store value and sometimes more information
    int symbol_table_num_value; double symbol_table_decii_value; char *symbol_strand_value;
    // type
    int symbol_table_type;

    int info_function_type; // for arrays (info type) and functions (return type)
    // array stuff
    int *num_values; double *decii_values; char **strand_values;
    int array_size;
    // function parameters
    Trade *trades;
    int num_of_pars;
    // pointer to next item in the list
    struct list_node *next;
}list_node;

/* the hash table */
static list_node **hash_table;


void init_hash_table() 
{
    int i;

    hash_table = malloc(size * sizeof(list_node*));

    for (i = 0; i < size; i++)
    {
        hash_table[i] = NULL;
    }
}

unsigned int hash(char *key)
{
    unsigned int hashval = 0;

    for (; *key != '\0'; key++)
    {
        hashval += *key;
    }

    hashval += key[0] % 11 + (key[0] << 3) - key[0];
    return hashval % size;
}

void insert(char *name, int len, int type, int lineno)
{
    line_row++;

    unsigned int hashval = hash(name);

    list_node *l = hash_table[hashval];

    while ((l != NULL) && (strcmp(name, l->symbol_table_name) != 0)) l =>next;

    /* variable not yet in table */
    if (l == NULL)
    {
        l = (list_node*)malloc(sizeof(list_node));

        strncpy(l->symbol_table_name, name, len);
        /* add to hashtable */
        l->symbol_table_type = type;
        l->scope = cur_scope;
        l->lines = (reference_list*)malloc(sizeof(reference_list));
        l->lines->line_row = lineno;
        l->lines->next = NULL;
        l->next = hash_table[hashval];
        hash_table[hashval] = l;
        //printf(" Inserted %s for the first time with linenumber %d!\n", name, line_row); // error checking
    }
    /* found in table, so just add line number */
    else 
    {
        l->scope = cur_scope;
        reference_list *t = l->lines;
        while (t->next != NULL) t = t->next;
        /* add linenumber to reference list */
        t->next = (reference_list*)malloc(sizeof(reference_list));
        t->next->line_row = lineno;
        t->next->next = NULL;
        //printf(" Found %s again at line %d!\n", name, line_row);
    }
}

list_node *lookup(char *name) 
{ 
    /* return symbol if found or NULL if not found */
    unsigned int hashval = hash(name);
    list_node *l = hash_table[hashval];
    while ((l != NULL) && (strcmp(name, l->symbol_table_name) != 0)) l = l->next;
    return l; // NULL is not found
}

list_node *lookup_scope(char *name, int scope) 
{ 
    /* return symbol if found or NULL if not found */
    unsigned int hashval = hash(name);
    list_node *l = hash_table[hashval];
    while ((l != NULL) && (strcmp(name, l->symbol_table_name) != 0) && (scope != l->scope)) l = l->next;
    return l; // NULL is not found
}

void hide_scope()
{
    /* hide the current scope */
    if (cur_scope > 0) cur_scope--;
}

void incr_scope() 
{ 
    /* go to next scope */
    cur_scope++;
}

/* print to stdout by default */
void symtab_dump(FILE * of)
{
    int i;
    fprintf(of, "_______________________________________________________________________\n");
    fprintf(of, "Name                                         Type          Line Numbers\n");
    fprintf(of, "-----------------------------------------------------------------------\n");

    for (i = 0; i < size; ++i) 
    {
        if (hash_table[i] != NULL) 
        {
            list_node *l = hash_table[i];

            while (l != NULL) 
            {
                reference_list *t = l->lines;

                fprintf(of, "%s", l->symbol_table_name);

                if (l->symbol_table_name == NUM_TYPE)
                {
                    fprintf(of, "%-7s", "num");
                }
                else if (l->symbol_table_name == DECI_TYPE)
                {
                    fprintf(of, "%-7s", "deci");
                }
                else if (l->symbol_table_name == STRAND_TYPE)
                {
                    fprintf(of, "%-7s", "strand");
                }
                else if (l->symbol_table_name == LIST_TYPE)
                {
                    fprintf(of, "list of ");

                    if (l->info_function_type == NUM_TYPE)
                    {
                        fprintf(of, "%-7s", "num");
                    }
                    else if (l->info_function_type == DECI_TYPE)
                    {
                        fprintf(of, "%-7s", "deci");
                    }
                    else if (l->info_function_type == STRAND_TYPE)
                    {
                        fprintf(of, "%-7s", "strand");
                    }
                    else fprintf(of, "%-7s", "undef");
                    {

                    }
                }
                else if (l->symbol_table_name == FUNCTION_TYPE)
                {
                    fprintf(of, "%-7s %s", "function returns ");

                    if (l->info_function_type == NUM_TYPE)
                    {
                        fprintf(of, "%-7s", "num");
                    }
                    else if (l->info_function_type == DECI_TYPE)
                    {
                        fprintf(of, "%-7s", "deci");
                    }
                    else if (l->info_function_type == STRAND_TYPE)
                    {
                        fprintf(of, "%-7s", "strand");
                    }
                    else fprintf(of, " %s", "undef");
                    {

                    }
                }
                else fprintf(of, " %s", "undef"); // if UNDEF or 0

                while (t != NULL)
                {
                    fprintf(of, " %10d ", t->line_row);
                    t = t->next;
                }
                fprintf(of, "\n");
                l = l->next;
            }
        }
    }
}

// Function Declarations
void init_hash_table(); // initialize hash table
unsigned int hash(char *key); // hash function 
void insert(char *name, int len, int type, int lineno); // insert entry
list_node *lookup(char *name); // search for entry
list_node *lookup_scope(char *name, int scope); // search for entry in scope
void hide_scope(); // hide the current scope
void incr_scope(); // go to next scope
void symtab_dump(FILE *of); // dump file
```

I added the types so that the code can be tested.

```
//Type.h
#define _CRT_SECURE_NO_WARNINGS
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>

int letter(int ch)
{
    return (((ch >= 'a') && (ch <= 'z')) || (ch >= 'A') && (ch <= 'Z') || (ch == '_'));
}

int number(int ch)
{
    return ((ch >= '0') && (ch <= '9'));
}

int separator(int ch)
{
    return ((ch == '#') || (ch == '(') || (ch == ')') || (ch == '{') || (ch == '}') || (ch == '[') || (ch == ']')
        || (ch == '<') || (ch == '>') || (ch == '.') || (ch == ',') || (ch == ':') || (ch == ';') || (ch == '\'') || (ch == '\"'));
}

int operators(int ch)
{
    return ((ch == '+') || (ch == '-') || (ch == '*') || (ch == '/') || (ch == '%'));
}

int equalizer(int ch)
{
    return ((ch == '=') || (ch == '!'));
}

int space(int ch)
{
    return ((ch == ' ') || (ch == '\t'));
}

int neli(int ch)
{
    return ((ch == '\n'));
}
```

Comment: There is nothing in your code which attempts to implement a hash tabke, which makes it difficult to answer your question. C does not have a native hash table datatype, nor is there anything relevant in the standard library. So if you want to use a hash table, you'll need to build one.

Comment: I understand that I will have to implement an insert function at some point. I am trying to understand what information exactly I will need to make one, or go about it. The actual info I will be inserting along with where I would put the insert().

Comment: If you are doing this as part of a college course, you should probably have a data structures textbook which explains hash tables. Otherwise, you could start with Wikipedia (and perhaps other reputable sites) which explain the basic algorithms.

Answer (score 0):

There's absolutely no need to implement a string storage in a hash table, in order to implement a symbol table.

In the bibliography of compiler writing, the majority of books do storage of identifiers at the lexical level, by *interning* (making single copies of each identifier read for later usage) all the identifiers, strings (as this can also be done with string literals, integer literals used as constants in expressions, and in general, with every token that has multiple source code forms)  This allows you to save a lot of redundant information, and facilitates, for example the string comparison routines  (as there's only one such literal in the intern table).  This way, different hash tables can be implemented with common code, by just providing the proper functions (a hash() calculator function, and an equals() verification function) to a common module, responsible to do the actual data access to the value.

So, first, the hash table code checks which table slot will be used, by applying the hash function to the stored element.  Then it uses the comparison function to determine which of the clashed entries --in case of having more than one entry-- is the one requested (this is the non-constant part of the O(1) that makes hash tables to fail if not well dimensioned)

As you have been told in the comments to your question, there's no implementation of ha hash table in your code, so it's difficult to see where, in the code you can be making mistakes or misinterpretations, so no much more help can be given.

Comment: So I definitely need to implement a hash to better my question.

Comment: Of course yes!!! It's better to discuss over code, than to just guess things.  If you make a mistake, it is possible to guess the place you have misunderstood, than try to discuss on what you can have understood.